# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/login / 'auth/register Angular

Tags: angular, routes, module

I need your help. I have an application that has a small structure and consists of:

1. `Authenticate` component - basic, for logging in and registering.
2. `Login` and `Register` are child components.

Also, I'm trying to use a module structure here. My base path consists of auth and if I go to login, the path is auth/login, registration is auth/register.

Unfortunately, my code below doesn't work as I would like it to. Can you please help to solve this? Thank you very much

AuthenticationRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'auth', component: AuthenticationComponent, children: [
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => LoginModule },
     { path: 'register', loadChildren: () => RegisterModule }
     ]
   }
];
```

LoginRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

RegisterRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RegisterComponent }
];
```

> Login and Register routing modules has connected to LoginModule and
> Register Module

AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'characters', loadChildren: () => AllCharactersModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'characters', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'characters/:id', loadChildren:  () => DifferentCharacterModule },
   { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => AuthenticationModule }
];
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Make sure your AuthenticationComponent contains <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated `auth` path (AppRoutingModule
and AuthenticationRoutingModule). For example, you can fix it that way:

AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
   ...
   { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => AuthenticationModule }
];
```

AuthenticationRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: AuthenticationComponent, children: [
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => LoginModule },
     { path: 'register', loadChildren: () => RegisterModule }
     ]
   }
];
```

And make sure your AuthenticationComponent contains router-outlet

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```